# How to extract sub arrays and rest of elements as Array from an Array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Let us say I have an array of arrays

```
aoa = [1, 2, [3, 4], 5, [6, 7, 8], 9]
```

I want to extract arrays and individual elements as array like below

```
[[1,2,5,9],[3,4],[6,7,8]] #=>order is not important
```

I tried this but not sure how to deal with individual elements

```
aoa.map{|i|  i if i.kind_of?(Array)}.compact #=> [[3, 4], [6, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [partition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition)  (and the `splat` operator, as pointed by @CarySwoveland)

```
a, i = aoa.partition{ |i| i.is_a? Array }
# => [[[3, 4], [6, 7, 8]], [1, 2, 5, 9]] 
[*a, i]
# => [[3, 4], [6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 5, 9]]
```

Comment: I prefer this solution. It is more direct, as it doesn't rely on the side effects of grouping by size.

Comment: Regarding your edit, what if `aoa` contains elements other than integers and arrays? Better to write `!i.is_a?(Array)`. I think `partition` is the way to go here, and I think that's what readers liked about your answer. Your "edit" is a distraction. I'd delete it and add the extra step to modify the array returned by `partition`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Agree, however I left the array check because the example in the question uses only integers. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

[`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) returns a `Hash`, whose values are what you want:

```
aoa.group_by(&:size).values.map(&:flatten)
# => [[1, 2, 5, 9], [3, 4], [6, 7, 8]]
```

---

@Cary Swoveland pointed out that using `size` to group is a bad idea, because subarrays with the same size as `Fixnum#size` would cause unexpected result. `group_by(&:class)` should be used instead.

Comment: I would add `.map(&:flatten)` to meet required form from question.

Comment: Almost the same, only `group_by(&:class)`

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev Your solution follows OP's words, while mine follows the example in the question. I guess you are right, as that's what the accepted answer does. I'll keep it as it is for now though.

Comment: Yu, I think you need to go with @YevgeniyAnfilofyev's suggestion, as `[1, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 2].group_by(&:size).values.map(&:flatten) 
 #=> [[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2]]` (because the array has 8 elements).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Isn't the result `[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]`?

Comment: `1.size #=> 8; 2.size #=> 8; [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].size #=> 8`, so that's why I got the result I reported (after testing). `Fixnum.size` returns bytes; `Array#size` returns number of elements.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ah, I got it now, you are right. I didn't get it because I'm working on a machine where `1.size` returns `4`.

Answer (score 2):

```
nested_a = [[]]
aoa.each {|e| e.is_a?(Array) ? nested_a << e : nested_a[0] << e  }
#remove 1st nested array if empty(Occurs if there were no individual elements)
nested_a.shift if nested_a[0].empty?
nested_a # => [[1, 2, 5, 9], [3, 4], [6, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: Interesting! You might consider `nested_a = aoa.each_with_object([[]]) { |e,arr|...`. Also, I suggest you remove `#` in your last (comment) line to remind readers that `nested_a` is needed there.

Answer (score 2):

Here are three other ways, for:

```
aoa = [1, 'cat', [3, 4], 5, [6, 7, 8], 9]
```

**1**

```
is_array = ->(e) { Array===e } 
[aoa.reject(&is_array)].concat(aoa.select(&is_array))
  #=> [[1, "cat", 5, 9], [3, 4], [6, 7, 8]]
```

**2**

Adding a step to @Doguita's use of [Enumerable#partition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition):

```
a, e = aoa.partition { |e| Array===e }
[e,*a]
  #=> [[1, "cat", 5, 9], [3, 4], [6, 7, 8]]
```

**3**

```
sorted = aoa.sort_by { |e| (Array===e) ? 1 : 0 }
[sorted.shift(aoa.count { |e| !(Array===e) })].concat(sorted)
  #=> [[1, "cat", 9, 5], [6, 7, 8], [3, 4]]
```

**What if `aoa` contains only arrays?**

All of these methods will return an array containing an empty array if all the elements of `aoa` are arrays. If an empty array is not desired, tack `.reject(&:empty?)` to the end. For example:

```
aoa = [[3, 4], [6, 7, 8]]
[aoa.reject(&is_array)].concat(aoa.select(&is_array))
  #=> [[], [3, 4], [6, 7, 8]]
[aoa.reject(&is_array)].concat(aoa.select(&is_array)).reject(&:empty?)
  #=> [[3, 4], [6, 7, 8]] 

aoa = [1, 'cat', 5, 9]
[aoa.reject(&is_array)].concat(aoa.select(&is_array))
  #=> [[1, "cat", 5, 9]]
[aoa.reject(&is_array)].concat(aoa.select(&is_array)).reject(&:empty?)
  #=> [[1, "cat", 5, 9]]
```

**You can instead use `reject!`, but if you do, avoid the pitfall!**

You can replace `reject(&:empty?)` with `reject!(&:empty?)`, which is a bit more efficient, but if you do, remember than `reject!` returns `nil` if no change is made, so you need to write:

```
 aoa = [1, 'cat', 5, 9]
 arr = [aoa.reject(&is_array)].concat(aoa.select(&is_array))
   #=> [[1, "cat", 5, 9]]
 arr.reject!(&:empty?)
   #=> nil
 arr
   #=> [[1, "cat", 5, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 >   aoa.inject([[]]) {|temp, x| x.is_a?(Array) ? temp << x : (temp.first << x); temp }
 #=> [[1, 2, 5, 9], [3, 4], [6, 7, 8]]
```